# Entity Framework 4.3 code first database naming

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 4.3 with a Code first approach.

With EF 4.3, it recommends using the new `<entityFramework />` config section to initialize the connection string for a context.

I've done some searching online, and I can't seem to find a convenient way to use this method for initializing a connection with a configurable database name.

For example, let say I have a `MyDBContext` entity in my application.
I want it to use the database name specified in the connection string from `Initial Catalog=MyDB;`

Using the old method from EF 4.1, I can do this no problem by adding the connection string to the `<connectionstring>` section in the config file.

```xml
<add name="MyDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

If I want to use the newer configsection that EF 4.3 supports, I have no way to specify a database name in the connection string. I have tried the following but the `Initial Catalog` property is ignored. I believe it is ignored for good reason, because the whole thing is a `DefaultConnectionFactory` that could be used by multiple Contexts in my application

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

The default DB name that my codefirst approach creates as a result of using this is `MyNamespace.MyDBContext`

I understand that there is one way to overwrite this default naming by passing a value to the `nameOrConnectionString` argument on the base `DBContext` object.

So I could do something like this:

```
public MyDBContext() : base("MyDB") { }
```

However, if I take this approach I end up hardcoding DB names into my application and personally I do not like this.

I'm wondering is there any way I can pass a database name for my DB context conveniently from the `Web.config` file, or should I just continue using the `<connectionstrings>` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How often do you think the database name will have to change?

That said, I haven't run into this issue myself (I'm fine hard-coding the database name - it shouldn't change) one option could be to store the database name you want in the Web.config as an application setting, and then have your code pull the value from there.

EDIT: You may also want to take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx :

```
public UnicornsContext()
    : base("name=UnicornsCEDatabase")
{
}
```

With that pulling the connection string with that particular name:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UnicornsCEDatabase"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
        connectionString="Data Source=Unicorns.sdf"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx this should still work in 4.3.

Comment: Generally I don't expect the DB name to change. But there could be cases where the DB name may collide with another DB name on the same SQL Instance. There's also the case if I want to run more than one instance of the same application on the same SQL Instance, it cannot be done without recompiling the application and changing the DB name. Not ideal.

Comment: Then I would say take a look at one of the two options above. Personally, it seems the ADO.NET blog's idea would be the best option of the two.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll stick with the connectionstring key in the Web.config file as per the referenced article.

Comment: Often, when I release a new version of my application, my customers prefer to test it against a test DB and must therefore be able to change the database name.